# Getting an Actionresult Parameter in MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a simple MVC application, where I am generating below path

```
@Html.ActionLink(@objcity.CityName, "AgentProfiles", "Home", new {@Id=objcity.MaProvision.ProvinceName+"/"+@objcity.CityName }, null)
```

It makes a url like this:

```
http://localhost:45896/Home/AgentProfiles/Ontario/testt
```

In the controller I have written this method:

```
public ActionResult AgentProfiles(String Id)
{
    //Code
}
```

Is it possible to get in /Ontario/testt in Id variable?

Comment: Are you trying to get the values of the `ProvinceName` and `CityName` in your action method?

Comment: have you routed these parametrs?show your route also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to get `/Ontario/testt` in **Id(route parameter)** for this you have to modify your default routes little bit or you have to make a custom route but in my opinion for your simple requirement try below answer.

Instead of

```
@Html.ActionLink(@objcity.CityName, "AgentProfiles", "Home", new {@Id=objcity.MaProvision.ProvinceName+"/"+@objcity.CityName }, null)
```

Modify Actionlink this way

```
@Html.ActionLink(@objcity.CityName, "AgentProfiles", "Home", new { ProvinceName=objcity.MaProvision.ProvinceName ,CityName = objcity.CityName }, null)
```

Controller Action :

```
public ActionResult AgentProfiles(string ProvinceName,string CityName ) //get ProvinceName and CityName which will be coming as querystring variables as shown here.
{......}
```

---

OR

EDIT :- Try this as per your comment.

Add one more route in RouteConfig.cs file inside AppStart folder as shown below :

```
routes.MapRoute(
      "MvcRoutes",                                            // Route name
      "{controller}/{action}/{provincename}/{cityname}",     // URL with parameters
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", provincename = "", cityname= "" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

Don't forget to put this custom route above default route.

Modify `ActionLink` as shown below :

```
 @Html.ActionLink(@objcity.CityName, "AgentProfiles", "Home", new { provincename = objcity.MaProvision.ProvinceName , cityname = objcity.CityName }, null)
```

Controller Action :

```
public ActionResult AgentProfiles(string provincename ,string cityname) 
{......}
```

Comment: Your Code is working Fine but i need this   http://localhost:45896/Home/AgentProfiles/Ontario/Punjabb  but your code show this             http://localhost:45896/Home/AgentProfiles?ProvinceName=Ontario&CityName=Punjabb

Answer (score 1):

you can modify your routing like-

```
  {controller}/{action}/{*catchall}
```

and in action method

```
public ActionResult AgentProfiles(string catchall)
{
// your code
}
```

Then you will have value /Ontario/testt in your catchall parameter which you can use in action method.

Comment: First you have to make sure like is AgentProfiles view page is available or not. If yes the what are you doing? are you trying to use /Ontario/testt to in url to open some page? If yes then I think there should be one controller with name Ontario and action method with name testt. please let me know in detail why you are getting 404- page not found error.